# boost asio cant set UDP source port

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, udp, boost-asio

I have written a UDP class with boost asio in C++. Currently when I send UDP data, a random source port is chosen. The destination port and ip address are passed in when the endpoint is created. How can I set the source port to send on port 8410? The code is as follows:

UDPClient.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

class UDPClient {
public:
    UDPClient(const std::string& ipAddress, const std::string& port);
    ~UDPClient();

    void Send(unsigned char* buff, int size);

private:
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint remoteEndpoint;
};
```

UDPClient.cpp

```
#include "UDPClient.h"

UDPClient::UDPClient(const std::string& ipAddress, const std::string& port) : socket{ ioService } {
    socket.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());

    boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast option(true);
    socket.set_option(option);

    this->remoteEndpoint = boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ipAddress), boost::lexical_cast<int>(port));
}

UDPClient::~UDPClient() {
    socket.close();
}

void UDPClient::Send(unsigned char* buff, int size) {
    const std::string stringBuffer(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buff), size);
    socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(stringBuffer, size), this->remoteEndpoint);
}
```

Comment: You need to bind UDP socket before sending if you want to send from predetermined port.

Comment: @SergeyA Thats what I figured, however, I am not sure how I can do this. Could you please give an example?

Comment: For future reference the solution is what SergeyA stated. After socket.open() I added socket.bind(boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), 8410)); and it worked great!